# How to import file contents into node

Tags: php, dom

I have a number of files containing a variety of html, text or more php code. I want to get the entire contents from a number of these files and append them to various elements.

I almost have it working but the contents is surrounded with quotes: here is my code

```
//load the document containing the li tags i wish to append html too
dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('dashboard.html'));
$widgets = $dom->getElementsByTagName('li');

//count through each li and append html from its corresponding file
foreach($widgets as $widget){
    $id = $widget->getAttribute('id');
    $widget_content = new DOMText(file_get_contents('widgets/'.$id.'/'.$id.'.html'));
    $widget->appendChild($widget_content);
}

//echo results
<?php echo $dom->saveHTML() ?>
```

this works fine other than the fact the li content is surrounded in quotes and so the html shows as plain text. I have tried using DOMNode and DOMElement instead of DOMText but I receive errors.

Warning: DOMNode::appendChild(): Couldn't fetch DOMNode

EDIT:

added where id is coming from

Comment: How should the code above work?, You missed to define `$id`. Also you would need to import the new text element into the document before you can add it to the `<li>` node. I would use `$dom->createTextNode()` instead.

Comment: `$id` is nowhere to be found or gone missing